# Problem burning mp3s to CDs

Tags: ubuntu-mate, cd, brasero

I am having a problem writing mp3s to CDs that will play in my car CD player. (It is mp3 capable.)

I have used Verbatim CD-RWs successfully in the past to write mp3s that play in my car.

I have used Brasero,XfBurn, and K3B.

And am writing it as a data disk because I can get more songs on it.

I have also tried writing at the lowest speed.

I also tried using CD-R discs.

Is there anything else I can try?

Using Ubuntu-Mate 18.04

Comment: In Brasero, are you burning them as a data project or as an audio project? Is your project's length less than 80 minutes? IIRC, 80 minutes is the max one can put on a traditional CD. I don't really know, I'm spitballing a this point. You may also want to edit your question to tell folks which version of Ubuntu you're using.

Comment: Has anything changed from the time you could write till now when you can't write?

Comment: Nothing has changed. I wrote them as an audio project and it does work. However my disks went from storing around 165 songs to 25. :-( @crip659

Comment: Odd, can see CD player not playing data files from beginning, but not stop playing them afterwards.  Sounds almost like CD player laser getting weak or is dirty, but usually they work or don't(no halfway).